# Openoffice or Libreoffice Writer navigation hotkey to jump to next heading

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, keyboard-navigation

It seems like such a basic thing that there must be a way to set a keyboard shortcut for this but I can't find the option anywhere.

I went to `Tools` > `Customize` > `Keyboard` and then under `Functions` in the `Category` pane selected `Navigate`. I looked for a "To Next Heading" or "To Next Chapter" option but didn't find anything.

There must be an option for this somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer you've been waiting for the past 8 years:

1. Assign shortcuts (`Tools → Customize → Keyboard`) to **Next Element** and **Previous Element** functions. (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>)
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to open **Navigator** window
3. Choose "Headings" from the uppermost dropdown menu
4. Close **Navigator** window
5. Use the shortcut keys you've defined in step 1.